# c# using const with DllImport

Tags: c#, constants, dllimport

I have a code example from a SDK, the DLL is written in C and calls for the following:

int getAttribute(const RawDevControl *control, RawDevAttribute *attribute)

I'm using

```
[DllImport(@"Dev.dll",
SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int getAttribute(const RControl *control, RAttribute *attribute);
```

But of course you can not use const as a type when defining this reference function.

How can I make this work with c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C# doesn't have the concept of const references, you don't really need to worry about it. On the DLL side, the code will still think you have a const pointer. Thus, your import changes to this:

```
[DllImport(@"Dev.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int getAttribute(RControl control, RAttribute attribute);
```

This, of course, assumes that both `RControl` and `RAttribute` have been defined in C#. If they are structs, follow the examples on MSDN for defining structs for use with P/Invoke. If they are classes, that's a different set of problems. In that case, it is best if the classes are COM-based.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration promises that the function doesn't alter the passed object.  So take advantage of that, tell the pinvoke marshaller that there's no point in copying it back.  Apply the [In] attribute:

```
[DllImport(@"Dev.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int getAttribute([In] ref RControl control, out RAttribute attribute);
```

Omit the *ref* or *out* keyword if you declared the argument types as classes instead of structs.